# Remove a substring only if not part of another substring

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove a substring from a string, but only if that substring is not part of another larger substring. I hope this was clear enough.

For example, I'd like to remove all occurencies of letter 'p' from string below, but only in case it's not followed by an 'e'. In other words, I'd like to remove 'p', but not if 'pe'.

```
apes are super people
```

should become:

```
apes are super peole
```

As you can see, only one occurency of letter 'p' is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with a [negative lookahead](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php), to make sure no 'e' follows 'p', then you can use the regex with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace("/p(?!e)/", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use use this negative lookahead regex:

```
/p(?!e)/
```

`p(?!e)` means match `p` if not followed by letter `e`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yM2oW7/1)

**Code:**

```
$re = "/p(?!e)/"; 
$str = "apes are super people"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str);
//=> apes are super peole
```